# Unable to Run Query in MySQL syntax error unexpected

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm running Workbench 5.2.47.

I have a long procedure I wrote with basic data checking. If a record did not exist in the database, the record would be inserted.

The procedure saved with no problems, but MySQL 5.5 throws an error when I try running it.

It is long, and has a lot of company sensitive data in it, or I would post it here.

I am trying to debug the procedure by executing small chunks of the code, but I can't seem to get Workbench to allow anything I try.

MySQL shows how to create a stored procedure in [5.1.5 Working with Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html).

Let me show you something very basic I am trying to write:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_test;

CREATE PROCEDURE my_test()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Employees;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

With that, Workbench gives me the error, "syntax error, unexpected CREATE, expecting $end".

[image: screenshot CREATE]

I don't understand that, but I need to get something done, so I am moving on.

I make a simpler query:

```
SET @Count=(SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl_object_users WHERE username='jp2code');
IF (@Count < 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO tbl_object_users (username, date_time) VALUES ('jp2code', NOW());
END IF;
```

Again, I get an error, this time on my IF statement.

[image: screenshot IF]

Next, I go into PhpMyAdmin to try running something from there using its database:

```
SET @Count=Count(id) FROM `tbl_object_users` WHERE `username`='jp2code';
```

It, too, tells me I have an error in my SQL syntax.

[image: screenshot phpMyAdmin]

I did download and install the newest Workbench 6, but it did not solve the problem - and I did not like the interface, so I uninstalled it and went back to Workbench 5.2.

### What is going on? SQL isn't that hard, so what is with these hurdles?

Comment: You can't use `IF` outside of a procedure.

Comment: But up in that screenshot, you can see it won't even let me `CREATE PROCEDURE my_test()`. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: @jp2code: You are missing something basic. You told MySQL that statements would be terminated with something other than a semicolon, and then you are attempting to use a semicolon to terminate a statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem with this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_test;
CREATE PROCEDURE my_test() ...
```

is that MySQL isn't seeing the semicolon at the end of the `DROP PROCEDURE` statement line as the end of the statement. This is because the preceding line told MySQL that the statement terminator was something other than a semicolon. You told MySQL that statements were going to be terminated with two dollar signs. So MySQL is reading the `DROP PROCEDURE` line, looking for the statement terminator. And the whole blob it reads is NOT a valid MySQL statement, it generates a syntax error.

The fix: either move the `DROP PROCEDURE` line *before* the `DELIMITER $$` line; or terminate the `DROP PROCEDURE` statement with the specified delimiter rather than a semicolon.

---

The second problem you report is a syntax error. That's occurring because MySQL doesn't recognize **`IF`** as the beginning of a valid SQL statement.

The `IF` statement is valid *only* within the context of a MySQL stored program (for example, within a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.)

The fix: Use an `IF` statement only within the context of a MySQL stored program.

---

The third problem you report is also a syntax error. That's occurring because you don't have a valid syntax for a `SET` statement; MySQL syntax for `SET` statement to assign a value to user variable is:

```
SET @uservar = expr
```

MySQL is expecting an *expression* after the equals sign. MySQL is *not* expecting a SQL statement.

To assign a value to a user variable as the result from a `SELECT` statement, do the assignment within the SELECT statement, for example:

```
SELECT @Count := Count(id) FROM `tbl_object_users` WHERE `username`='jp2code'
```

Note that the assignment operator inside the `SELECT` statement is **`:=`** (colon equals), not just **`=`**.

Comment: That is an awesome answer! Thank you. `SELECT @Count := ` appears to be my biggest mistake. I've used **SQL Server** for years, but less than 1 year with MySQL. The two are very different!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_test$$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_test()
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM `customer_to_pay`;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: +1. That does answer part of it, but I marked spencer's answer because it addressed all of the issues I had. Thank you.