# Missing 'colon' error in MySQL Trigger declaration

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, triggers, mysql-workbench

Hello everybody and firstly thanks for your patience and help!

I just got stuck while creating a trigger in MySQL (I'm usin' MySQL WorkBench 6.3 on Ubuntu 16.10).

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_device 
BEFORE INSERT ON dummyPT_data.devices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.dtype != "HOST" && NEW.ipaddr != NULL || NEW.netmask != NULL || NEW.dfgateway != NULL)
    THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'The device type is uncompatible with data inserted');
    END IF;
END;
```

The code editor underlines the function `raise_application_error` and says: `Syntax error: missing 'colon'`

I could't find any errors in the text. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code. Now looks like this:

`DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_device 
BEFORE INSERT ON dummyPT_data.devices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.dtype != "HOST" && NEW.ipaddr IS NOT NULL || NEW.netmask IS NOT NULL || NEW.dfgateway IS NOT NULL)
 THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'The device type is uncompatible with data inserted');
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;`

And I get the same error plus a error on ending `DELIMITER` keyword, it says `Syntax error: DELIMITER (identifier) is not valid input in this position`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious syntax error that jumps to me

```
!= NULL
```

should be

```
IS NOT NULL
```

Besides this one,wrap your trigger with DELIMITER

Answer (score 0):

maybe is a problem with delimiter, did you change it?

look this

[Unable to Run Query in MySQL syntax error unexpected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061585/unable-to-run-query-in-mysql-syntax-error-unexpected)

and if you change your delimiter you must put the new delimiter en the last END

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_device 
BEFORE INSERT ON dummyPT_data.devices
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.dtype != "HOST" && NEW.ipaddr != NULL || NEW.netmask != NULL || NEW.dfgateway != NULL)
 THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'The device type is uncompatible with data inserted');
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```